# The plugin `path_provider_extention` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

The plugin `path_provider_extention` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

```
getPdfFiles() async {
    List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
    var root = storageInfo[0].rootDir;
    var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
    files = await fm.filesTree(
        excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/Android"], extensions: ["pdf"]);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please check once